# Ruby cron job throws "no such file to load -- deprecated" error

Tags: ruby, cron

I scheduled this cronjob:

```
ruby twitter_bots/tweet_bots.rb
```

**tweet_bots.rb:**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require '/home/david/twitter_bots/twitterbot.rb'

mcnulty = TwitterBot.new('jamesmcnulty')
mcnulty.tweet
mcnulty.reply
mcnulty.close
```

**twitterbot.rb:**

```
require 'dbi'
require 'twitter'

class TwitterBot
    ...
```

**The cron has these environmental variables:**

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/david/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
HOME=/home/david
LOGNAME=david
```

**But it throws this error:**

```
/home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- deprecated (LoadError)
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/dbi.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/david/twitter_bots/twitterbot.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from twitter_bots/tweet_bots.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

I can see that the error comes from `/home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/dbi.rb:48` where it has `require "deprecated"`

But I have the deprecated gem v 2.0.1 installed. I also tried it with version 3.0.0.

When I run it manually, it works. What's wrong with the cron?

Comment: When I had deprecated v 3 installed, running it manually threw this error: `/home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/dbi/utils/date.rb:57:in `<class:Date>': undefined method `deprecate' for DBI::Date:Class (NoMethodError)`. So I uninstalled it.

Comment: Can you paste the code for twitterbot.rb?

regarding v 3 - Can you try with ruby - 1.9.3? when you try use either rvm or uninstall ruby properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am  guessing you need the `deprecated` Gem.

try:

```
[sudo] gem install deprecated
```

Comment: hm, i have the deprecated gem already installed. It's version 2.0.1.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3. But now I get this error in `twitterbot.rb` for `require 'dbi'`: `/home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- dbi (LoadError)`. I have dbi 0.4.5 installed for v 1.9.3.

Comment: Re: load path. I had this in `tweet_bots.rb` as the 2nd line before: `$LOAD_PATH << '/home/david/twitter_bots/'` but that didn't solve it.

Comment: no need to write require 'rubygems', its come by default after 1.9.1, just remove and can add require 'dbi' and check if its works

Comment: it should work after adding require 'dbi', is it? see here more information - RubyGems will always give priority to libraries installed in site_ruby for  https://gist.github.com/342220

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I moved this discussion to chat. Let me know if you can't find it.